# Cannot import Three.js into my project: server returns with an error of 404 (three.js)

Tags: javascript, import, module

I was checking my portfolio, which was working fine a few weeks ago, and i found out that my three.js model isn't showing anymore (I haven't modified anything since it was working fine.), and when I checked the errors in the console, it gave me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`.
 I was importing three.js in a main.js file like this:
`import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three'`, so I changed the import to: `import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.js'`, but now it returns an error of 404. what should I do?
This is my file structure:

[image: structure]

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to install three.js is described here:

https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation

should be like so:

`import * as THREE from 'three';`